# Python for loop with adding to an equation?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, equation

I need some help in this program. I need help figuring out how to make it calculate interest for a period over ten years (including the first one). This is as far as i have gotten on my own. I would greatly appreciate some insight to this problem.

Thanks.
*The "print() is just for spacing so that the program looks cleaner.

```
p= int(input(" Intial Amount? "))
print()
r= float(input(" Rate? (Decimal) "))
print()
n= int(input(" Number Of Times Compunded? (Yearly) "))
print()
t= float(input(" Number Of Years? "))
A= p*(1+r/n)**(n*t)
print()
print( " Interest At Final Year","$",format(A, ',.2f'))
print()
for i in range (10):
    print(format(i+1, '3')," Year","Interest","$",format(A,',.2f'))
```

Comment: To add space just press enter. and leave a blank space. Python understands that and it won't mess up your code. No need to use `print()`. Also, to define a few variables at once, you can use something like this: `p, r, n, t = int(input("Principal: ")), float(input("Rate (Decimal): ")), int(input("Number of Compounds Annually: ")), float(input("Number of Years: "))`. This should work for `input` or `raw_input` statements.

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND: Seriously, you'd write a 153-character statement (or use backslash continuations) to cram all four of those assignments on one line? If you're actually calling `input` four times, it's much more readable to put them on separate lines. (Also, `input` isn't a statement—if it were, you couldn't put them on the same line in the first place. Plus, he's clearly using Python 3, so there is no `raw_input`.)

Comment: @abarnert: I realized he was using Python 3 afterwards, but was unable  edit my comment as it had been 5 minutes after posting. Regardless, I was just saying that you can assign them on one line; he doesn't necessarily have to use it for this case.

Answer (score 3):

In the body of your loop, you are not updating the values of any of the variables. You need to update A at every iteration or store the intermediate results in some other variable. As an example, see the following:

```
def compound_interest(r, n, initial):
    current_value = initial
    for i in range(n):
        current_value *= (1 + r)
        print(current_value)
```

I use the current_value variable to save the intermediate results of the loop. If I had simply done initial * (1 + r) at every iteration then the value of initial would never change; the result of the calculation must be saved if you want to keep using it.

Comment: I understand how the equation works. I'm trying to make it count out the interest up to 10 years after the first investment. (bot trying to sound like a butt, sorry if the first question was a little to vague).

Comment: Okay. I am still very new to python as it is. I just might not be making myself very clear on this. Please copy and past my program into python and run it. I think that will make it more clear. At the very end of the program it will count 1-10 but it will have the same amount as the first calculation. I need help making it add the new values to add up while the "n" and the "p" are changing.

Comment: If you look in my answer, you can see that I save the initial value in variable called current_value. At every iteration of the loop, I multiply the current_value by (1 + r) and store the result back in current_value. current_value *= (1 + r) does the same thing as current_value = current_value * (1 + r).

Comment: Thank you guys for all of the help. This is what i ended up with and it does what i wanted it to do. :) I'm going to apologize now for this not being in the right format.

Comment: p= int(input(" Initial Amount? "))

print()

r= float(input(" Rate? (Decimal) "))

print()

n= int(input(" Number Of Times Compounded? (Yearly) "))

print()

t= float(input(" Number Of Years? ")) 

A= p*(1+r/n)**n*t

print()


for year in range (10):
    Initial = p + A
    for period in range(n):
        p = p * (1 + r/n)
    print(format(year+1, '3')," Year","Interest","$",format(p,',.2f'))

Answer (score 0):

> At the very end of the program it will count 1-10 but it will have the same amount as the first calculation.

Yes, that's because the only thing that happens in that loop is the `print` call. You're just calculating `A` all at once, before you get into the loop, and then using the same `A` over and over again.

> I need help making it add the new values to add up while the "n" and the "p" are changing.

Well, you aren't changing `n` or `p`, and I don't think you need to. But you do need to change *something*. If you want to print a different value of `A` each time through the loop, you have to recalculate next year's `A` based on the previous year's `A`, or whatever else goes into determining the right value.

For example:

```
for year in range (10):
    jan1balance = p
    for period in range(n):
        p = p * (1 + r)
    print(format(year+1, '3')," Year","Interest","$",format(p - jan1balance,',.2f'))
```

Or:

```
for year in range (10):
    yearlyinterest = 0
    for period in range(n):
        periodinterest = p * r
        yearlyinterest += periodinterest
        p += periodinterest
    print(format(year+1, '3')," Year","Interest","$",format(yearlyinterest,',.2f'))
```